# how to specify the group to authenticate user in ldaploginmodule and jboss configuration

Tags: authentication, filter, jboss, ldap

I would like to authenticate the user only if he in a specific group.

To my test I have two users:

- one user is in the **FIRST GROUP**
- other is in de **SECOND GROUP**

I have an active directory :

```
CN=Users,DC=XXXX,DC=com
  ---usrA      
  ---usrB      
  ---group1      
  ---group2
```

`usrA` is in the `group1`, `usrB` is in the `group2` 
and I authenticate the user via JBoss with `LdapLoginModule` in the `standalone.xml`.

standelone.xml:

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" flag="sufficient">
  <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
  <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://192.168.1.18"/>
  <module-option name="java.naming.allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
  <module-option name="userfilter" value="(&amp;(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(cn={USERNAME})((primaryGroupID=1109)))"/>                       
  <module-option name="principalDNSuffix" value="@XXXX.com"/>                           
  <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
</login-module>
```

When `(primaryGroupID=1109)` = `group1`.

The result is:

- the `usrA` success login
- **the `usrB` success too**

So the filter used does not work properly or is not used at all, and I have no error.

I tested the query of `userfilter` in active directory and it returns me well "`usrA`"

Someone has an idea of the problem? Anyone have another way to use a user according to his group?

Comment: Is the user filter actually `"(&amp;(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(cn={USERNAME})((primaryGroupID=1109)))"` ? Try this one: `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(cn={USERNAME})(primaryGroupID=1109))`

Comment: hy acdcjunior and thx to help me. but when i try without &amp; i have a parsing erreur betwen & and ( .. ...

Comment: 14:34:00,583 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
 at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_04]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '(' (code 40) (expected a name start character)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [259,71]

Comment: The exception seems not to be about the `&`, but a `(`. Try: `value="&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(cn={USERNAME})(primaryGroupID=1109)"`